# Is there a better way to format or reduce code for DBOperation for SQLite Insert,Update,Delete Action?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, class

My code is below. can I reduce this code? If yes then how? Or any better way to do this type of code for SQLite Insert, Update, Delete Functionality? This is single table example but need to build multiple tables. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

```
    package fourever.amaze.mics;

        import android.content.ContentValues;
        import android.content.Context;
        import android.database.Cursor;
        import android.database.SQLException;
        import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
        import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
        import android.util.Log;
        import java.util.ArrayList;
        import java.util.List;
        import java.util.Map;
        import java.util.Set;
        import fourever.amaze.entities.ReminderEntity;

        public class DBOperation {

            private static final String TAG = "DBOperation";
            private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Amaze";
            public static final String TABLE_REMINDER = "tbl_reminder";
            private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 3;

            // START TABLE REMINDER
            public static final String KEY_id = "id";
            public static final String KEY_USERID = "user_id";
            public static final String KEY_REMINDER_TITLE = "reminder_title";
            public static final String KEY_REMIND_ME = "remind_me";
            public static final String KEY_ALARM_DATE = "alarm_date";
            public static final String KEY_ALARM_TIME = "alarm_time";
            public static final String KEY_REPEAT_REMINDER = "repeat_reminder";
            public static final String KEY_NOTES = "notes";
            public static final String KEY_NEXT_REMINDER_DATE = "next_reminder_date";
            public static final String DATABASE_TABLE_REMINDER = "create table IF NOT EXISTS "
                    + TABLE_REMINDER + " (" + KEY_id + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                    + KEY_USERID + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                    + KEY_REMINDER_TITLE + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                    + KEY_REMIND_ME + " TEXT, "
                    + KEY_ALARM_DATE + " TEXT, "
                    + KEY_ALARM_TIME + " TEXT, "
                    + KEY_REPEAT_REMINDER + " TEXT, "
                    + KEY_NOTES + " TEXT, "
                    + KEY_NEXT_REMINDER_DATE + " TEXT)";
            // END TABLE REMINDER

            private final Context context;
            private static DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
            private SQLiteDatabase db;

            public DBOperation(Context ctx)
            {
                this.context = ctx;
                DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);

            }

            public DBOperation open() throws SQLException {
                db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                return this;
            }

            public void close() {
                DBHelper.close();
            }

            private class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
                DatabaseHelper(Context context)
                {
                    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
                    db = this.getWritableDatabase();
                }

                @Override
                public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
                {
                    try {
                        db.execSQL(DATABASE_TABLE_REMINDER);
                    } catch (SQLException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
                {
                    Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                            + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");

                    if (newVersion > oldVersion) {
                        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE_REMINDER);
                        onCreate(db);
                    }
                }
            }

            public long insertTableData(String tablename, ContentValues values)
                    throws SQLException {
                ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
                Set<Map.Entry<String, Object>> s = values.valueSet();
                String new_val = "";
                for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : s) {
                    new_val = values.getAsString(entry.getKey());
                    contentValues.put(entry.getKey(), new_val);
                }
                return db.insert(tablename, null, contentValues);
            }

            public List<ReminderEntity> getTableData(String tbl_name) {

                List<ReminderEntity> ChatList = new ArrayList<ReminderEntity>();
                db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + tbl_name + " order by alarm_date desc, alarm_time desc", null);

                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                        ReminderEntity dbEntity = new ReminderEntity();
                        dbEntity.setId(cursor.getString(0));
                        dbEntity.setUser_id(cursor.getString(1));
                        dbEntity.setReminder_title(cursor.getString(2));
                        dbEntity.setRemind_me(cursor.getString(3));
                        dbEntity.setAlarm_date(cursor.getString(4));
                        dbEntity.setAlarm_time(cursor.getString(5));
                        dbEntity.setRepeat_reminder(cursor.getString(6));
                        dbEntity.setNotes(cursor.getString(7));
                        dbEntity.setNext_reminder_date(cursor.getString(8));
                        ChatList.add(dbEntity);
                    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                }

                cursor.close();
                return ChatList;
            }


            public void updateRow(String id, String remind_date ) {
                SQLiteDatabase db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();

                ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
                args.put(KEY_NEXT_REMINDER_DATE, remind_date);

                db.update(TABLE_REMINDER, args, KEY_id + "=" + id, null);
            }
        }





        package fourever.amaze.mics;

        import java.io.BufferedReader;
        import java.io.IOException;
        import java.io.InputStreamReader;
        import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
        import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
        import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
        import java.net.URL;
        import java.net.URLConnection;
        import java.net.URLEncoder;
        import java.util.HashMap;
        import java.util.Map;

        /**
         * Created by jayshri on 24/7/15.
         */
        public class PutUtility {

            private Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            private static HttpURLConnection httpConnection;
            private static BufferedReader reader;
            private static String Content;
            private StringBuffer sb1;
            private StringBuffer response;

            public void setParams(Map<String, String> params) {
                this.params = params;
            }

            public void setParam(String key, String value) {
                params.put(key, value);
            }

            public String getData(String Url) {


                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                try {
                    // Defined URL  where to send data

                    URL url = new URL(Url);

                    URLConnection conn = null;
                    conn = url.openConnection();

                    // Send POST data request
                    httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
                    httpConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                    httpConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");

                    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(httpConnection.getInputStream()));
                    String inputLine;
                    response = new StringBuffer();

                    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                        response.append(inputLine);
                    }
                    in.close();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    try {
                        reader.close();
                    } catch (Exception ex) { }
                }

                return response.toString();
            }


            public String postData(String Url) {


                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                for (String key : params.keySet()) {
                    String value = null;
                    value = params.get(key);


                    if (sb.length() > 0) {
                        sb.append("&");
                    }
                    sb.append(key + "=" + value);
                }

                try {
                    // Defined URL  where to send data

                    URL url = new URL(Url);

                    URLConnection conn = null;
                    conn = url.openConnection();

                    // Send POST data request
                    httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
                    httpConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                    httpConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    httpConnection.setDoInput(true);
                    httpConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                    OutputStreamWriter wr = null;

                    wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
                    wr.write(sb.toString());
                    wr.flush();

                    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(httpConnection.getInputStream()));
                    String inputLine;
                    response = new StringBuffer();

                    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                        response.append(inputLine);
                    }
                    in.close();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    try {

                        reader.close();
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                    }
                }


                return response.toString();
            }


            public String putData(String Url) {


                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                for (String key : params.keySet()) {
                    String value = null;
                    try {
                        value = URLEncoder.encode(params.get(key), "UTF-8");
                        if (value.contains("+"))
                            value = value.replace("+", "%20");

                        //return sb.toString();


                        // Get the server response

                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    if (sb.length() > 0) {
                        sb.append("&");
                    }
                    sb.append(key + "=" + value);
                }

                try {
                    // Defined URL  where to send data

                    URL url = new URL(Url);

                    URLConnection conn = null;
                    conn = url.openConnection();

                    // Send PUT data request
                    httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
                    httpConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                    httpConnection.setRequestMethod("PUT");
                    httpConnection.setDoInput(true);
                    httpConnection.setDoOutput(false);
                    OutputStreamWriter wr = null;

                    wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
                    wr.write(sb.toString());
                    wr.flush();

                    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                    ;
                    String line = null;

                    // Read Server Response
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        // Append server response in string
                        sb1.append(line + " ");
                    }

                    // Append Server Response To Content String
                    Content = sb.toString();


                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    try {

                        reader.close();
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                    }
                }
                // Send PUT data request
                return Url;

            }


            public String deleteData(String Url) {


                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                for (String key : params.keySet()) {

                    try {
                        // Defined URL  where to send data

                        URL url = new URL(Url);

                        URLConnection conn = null;
                        conn = url.openConnection();

                        // Send POST data request
                        httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
                        httpConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                        httpConnection.setRequestMethod("DELETE");
                        httpConnection.connect();


                        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

                        String line = null;

                        // Read Server Response
                        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                            // Append server response in string
                            sb1.append(line + " ");
                        }

                        // Append Server Response To Content String
                        Content = sb.toString();


                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                        try {

                            reader.close();
                        } catch (Exception ex) {
                        }
                    }



                }
                return Url;

            }
        }


        public void UploadReminderToServer() {
                List<ReminderEntity> datalist = dbOperation.getTableData(DBOperation.TABLE_REMINDER);
                if (datalist.size() != 0) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < datalist.size(); i++) {
                        String Id = datalist.get(i).getId();
                        String user_id = datalist.get(i).getUser_id();
                        String reminder_title = datalist.get(i).getReminder_title();
                        String remind_me = datalist.get(i).getRemind_me();
                        String alarm_date = datalist.get(i).getAlarm_date();
                        String alarm_time = datalist.get(i).getAlarm_time();
                        String repeat_reminder = datalist.get(i).getRepeat_reminder();
                        String notes = datalist.get(i).getNotes();
                        String next_reminder_date = datalist.get(i).getNext_reminder_date();

                        new ServiceInsert().execute(Id, user_id, reminder_title, remind_me,
                                alarm_date, alarm_time, repeat_reminder, notes, next_reminder_date);
                    }
                }
            }

            private class ServiceInsert extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

                // ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
                private String res;

                @Override
                protected void onPreExecute() {
                    //  mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(Add_ReminderActivity.this,"", "Registering...");
                }

                @Override
                protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

                    res = null;
                    PutUtility put = new PutUtility();

                    try {
                        res = put.getData("http://192.168.0.109/amaze/webservice/reminder_add.php?sql_id=" + params[0] + "&user_id=" + params[1] + "&reminder_title=" + Uri.encode(params[2]) + "&remind_me=" + params[3] + "&alarm_date=" + params[4] + "&alarm_time=" + params[5] + "&repeat_reminder=" + params[6] + "&notes=" + Uri.encode(params[7]) + "&next_reminder_date=" + params[8]);
                        Log.v("res", res);
                    } catch (Exception objEx) {
                        //  mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                        objEx.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    return res;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(String res) {

                    try {
                        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(res.toString());
                        for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                            String errorcode = json.getString("errorcode");
                            if (errorcode.equals("0")) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Called..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                // customtoast.ShowToast(Add_ReminderActivity.this, "Reminder set succesfully", R.layout.blue_toast);
                                //  mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                                //  Add_ReminderActivity.this.finish();
                            } else {
                                //  String errormsg = json.getString("errormsg");
                                //  customtoast.ShowToast(Add_ReminderActivity.this, errormsg, R.layout.red_toast);
                                // mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        }
                        //  mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                    } catch (Exception objEx) {
                        objEx.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }



        package com.fourever.testproject.mainclasses;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.HeaderViewListAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.fourever.testproject.R;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private NavigationView navigationView;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ImageView imgnavigation;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

        final Menu menu = navigationView.getMenu();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
            menu.add(1,i,i,"Runtime item "+ i);
        }

        for (int i = 0, count = navigationView.getChildCount(); i < count; i++) {
            final View child = navigationView.getChildAt(i);
            if (child != null && child instanceof ListView) {
                final ListView menuView = (ListView) child;
                final HeaderViewListAdapter adapter = (HeaderViewListAdapter) menuView.getAdapter();
                final BaseAdapter wrapped = (BaseAdapter) adapter.getWrappedAdapter();
                wrapped.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }

        Resources resources = getResources();
        final int resourceId = resources.getIdentifier("menu", "drawable",
                getPackageName());

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
        imgnavigation = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgnavigation);

        imgnavigation.setImageResource(resourceId);

        imgnavigation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                } else {
                    mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                }
            }
        });

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.app_name, R.string.app_name) {

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();

        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                int id = menuItem.getItemId();
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                switch (id){
                    case R.id.nav_home:
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_about:
                        break;

                }
                return false;
            }
        });

    }
}



    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/relativesearch"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imgnavigation"
                        android:layout_width="36dp"
                        android:layout_height="36dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:background="@drawable/menu" />

                </RelativeLayout>

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_below="@id/relativesearch">

                </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

            </RelativeLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Use Content provider

Comment: An ORM would autogenerate this code for you.  A good one will do so while not preventing you from direct querying when needed.

Comment: Please send me sample or some example code. I am new in this

Comment: any example for Content provider? Mohom.R

Comment: Use ORM. [5 best android orms](https://www.sitepoint.com/5-best-android-orms/)

Comment: Any example of Content provider?